# Possibility of comparing an "option value" with only the first number of a database record?

Tags: php, html, sql, range

Sorry for the fairly ambiguous and long question.

I am creating a search form for a packaging database and over the past few days I have had a few problems with creating one of the forms that searches for the height of a packet. I want the form to display all results associated with a users input instead of it just returning the exact results. I couldn't get anything like that working. So I have resorted to creating a dropdown box that searches within a range.

HTML Dropdown:

```
        <body>
               <label for="trayheight">Height: </label>
                <select name="trayheight">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="1">100 - 199 range</option>
                    <option value="2">200 - 299 range</option>
                    <option value="3">300 - 399 range</option>
                </select><br />
        </body>
```

Here is the dropdown ranges (I also will be adding a range that searches for the 70 - 80 packets). As you can see the option value in each just consists of one number ("1,2,3"), this is so the database will return any results that has (for example) a 1 in it. So if a user searches for something in the "100-199" range, the SQL query will return all the results that are within that range, but currently also return anything with a "1" in it e.g. height "201". I want to change it so the SQL query will take the value and then use it to compare it to the first number in a record e.g. the 1 in (1)21, so the results that return should only be within that range and nothing else such as "212" won't return. Is there some form of server code that would deal with this?

Here is my server side code:

```
       <body>

        <?php
            $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
                   mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);

            if (!$con)
                { 
                    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                }

            $descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']); 
            $width   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['width']);
            $depth   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['depth']);

            $varHeight= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayheight']);
            $varRange = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayrange']);
            $varType  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['traytype']);
            $varShape = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayshape']);
            $varImage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imagename']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE 
                        description LIKE '%".$descrip."%'  
                    AND trayheight  LIKE '%".$varHeight."%'
                    AND trayrange   LIKE '%".$varRange."%' 
                    AND traytype    LIKE '%".$varType."%' 
                    AND trayshape   LIKE '%".$varShape."%'";


            $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query))
                    { 
                        echo '<br /> <img src="   '. $row['imagename'] . '" width="180" length="100">';
                        echo '<br /> Tool Code:   '. $row['toolcode'];
                        echo '<br /> Description: '. $row['description']; 
                        echo '<br /> Tray range:  '. $row['trayrange']; 
                        echo '<br /> Tray type:   '. $row['traytype'];
                        echo '<br /> Tray size:   '. $row['traysize']; 
                        echo '<br /> Tray shape:  '. $row['trayshape'] . '<br />' . '<br />';  
                    }

                if (mysql_num_rows($r_query) <= 0){
                    echo 'No results match your search, please try again';
               }


        ?>
      </body>
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just construct the range:

```
if (isset($varHeight) && !empty($varHeight)) {
    $low = intval($varHeight."00");
    $high= intval($varHeight."99");
} else {
   $low = intval("000");
   $high= intval("999");
}
```

and change the sql query to search for this range:

```
AND trayheight  LIKE '%".$varHeight."%'
```

to

```
"AND trayheight  BETWEEN '".$low."' AND '".$high."'"
```

Of course proper validation should be placed to ensure that `$varHeight` is a number (presumably between 1 and 9)

**UPDATED** in order to catch the absence of `$varHeight` filter. This assumes that the total minimum of all possible values for `$varHeight` is `000` and the total maximum is `999`

Comment: Unfortunately this does stop all the other search functions from working when the height option is on blank.

Comment: Then conditionally remove this `AND` from you SQL Query statement if the `$varHeight` is not passed or give the range the total minimum and total maximum respectively for unbiased `$varHeight` searches. I'll update my answer

Comment: Ahh right, so if the varHeight has no value then pass it and take values from the other forms. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't return any results if the varHeight is left blank and you search for something using the other forms. The only way results return is if you use just the height range dropdown or that and another form to get more specified results.

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to how you would go about getting it to search for values under 100? I have tried by changing the database to have values like "098" and then having the <option value="0"> but that just returns all the results.

Comment: Hm...integers in `PHP` by default don't have any leading zeros. `098` is the same to `98`. For this to work remove the `intval` function for the code posted above and try again.

Comment: Seems the value in the database won't allow me to put a zero before the 98. Hmmm.

Comment: Removal of the `intval` code doesn't fix the 1-100 range unfortunately. Is it maybe because `<option value="0">` would that be changed?